# Gradle subproject build dependency

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, multi-project, subproject

I have a dependency problem and I do not know how to solve it.

I have a project A, B and C.

A needs B and C

B needs C

My directory structure looks like this:

```
A
|-settings.gradle
|-build.gradle
|-lib
   |- B
   |- C
```

settings.gradle content:

```
include 'lib/B'
include 'lib/C'
```

build.gradle content:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
  compile project(':lib/B'), 
          project(':lib/C') 
}

project(':lib/B'){
  dependencies {
    compile project(':lib/C')
  }
}
```

If I do NOT declare the project(':lib/B'){...} part, project B can not be build because of dependencies.

If I declare the project(':lib/B'){...} part, Gradle tells me : Could not find method compile() for arguments [project ':lib/C'] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.pendencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@221bad.

How am I able to solve it, or compile C before B?

PS: Data structure changes are not possible.

Comment: Do you have a separate build.gradle for your B and C subprojects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please, try to add

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}
```

to your main `build.gradle`

Comment: This fixes the issue, although I already have separate build.gradle files for my B and C which are containing this plugin.

Comment: This answer helped me to realize that inside scope of `subprojects/allprojects {}`  you can't use plugin specific blocks (e.g. `dependencies {}` from `java` plugin) unless you apply plugin explicitly.